# How to Display all other products in Product description page by category

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

I am editing Virtue mart's **Product Description** view, i just want to display all the other remaining products in the  Product Description page itself.
 For example:

> "A category having 10 products, now i m in a description page of a
>   product which is 1 among 10. How to show remaining 9 products"

Any One Help me with the code part..(or) Is this can be done with the Back-end Settings???

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VM2.x then you can achieve this with accessories option or related categories.

In the product create/edit form in admin side last tab (Custom field) have option for adding Related Category and Related Products.

The related products are showing in the details page.
The related category will show the category details and link.

Hope its help you..